# Conditional Check on Matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement, boolean-computation

Suppose I have the following matrix (i,j):

```
mat = {{19.8134, 54.7015, 64.1866, 75.5597, 88.8358, 83.7313, 93.0299, 
  88.2537, 101.03, 108.873, 91.8731, 88.097, 82.0075, 88.7164, 
  83.5672, 69.9254, 56.0149, 31.4328, 19.4179, 6.40299, 1.48507, 
  0.410448, 0.171642, 0, 0}, {24.2741, 52.6815, 64.4667, 74.8593, 
  87.6222, 87.1926, 96.3407, 90.0667, 98.2519, 103.496, 89.7926, 
  85.1259, 83.4889, 88.7111, 86.1852, 75.4296, 53.7778, 34.0667, 
  19.6889, 7.40741, 2.16296, 0.348148, 0.00740741, 0, 0}, {18.4632, 
  50.6544, 60.5735, 72.5441, 86.0956, 84.9485, 91.1103, 84.8603, 
  94.3897, 100.463, 83.6324, 82.9412, 77.4853, 79.6324, 77.9485, 
  61.9118, 48.7574, 27.8309, 13.8824, 5.96324, 1.60294, 0.529412, 
  0.0294118, 0, 0}, {19.1212, 59.0985, 71.6818, 86.8182, 96.553, 
  91.5455, 100.402, 92.6515, 111.068, 111.909, 95.7803, 94.3864, 
  92.75, 90.8182, 95.3561, 86.197, 73.6136, 51.5682, 40.6742, 15.1515,
   3.30303, 0.848485, 0.0757576, 0.030303, 0.030303}, {19.6083, 
  55.5917, 66.5583, 75.575, 87.6, 89.1417, 96.1083, 92.6917, 108.375, 
  117.3, 96.7333, 91.8167, 86.6583, 91.7333, 93.45, 79.5333, 60.275, 
  36.95, 24.3583, 9.60833, 1.76667, 0.416667, 0.00833333, 0.0333333, 
  0}}
```

The following is my criteria vector that each element corresponding to each row of the above matrix:

```
check = {7.94021, 7.95033, 7.44576, 8.83645, 8.38877}
```

Here is my criteria. If the element in `mat[[i,All]]` is less than the corresponding element in `check[[i]]` vector, I want to replace with the following vector

```
replacevec = {79.4021, 79.5033, 74.4576, 88.3645, 83.8877}
```

where each element `(replacevec[[i]])` correspond to each row in `mat` .

Could you give me suggestions?

Thank you for help.

Comment: could you please clarify "If the element in mat[[i,All]] is less than the corresponding element in check[[i]] vector" as `mat[[i,All]]` is a vector of length 25. What is being compared? Is it a single comparison for each row or is each element in row being compared with check element for that row?

Comment: Do you mean `mat[[i,All]]` or `mat[[All,i]]`? mat[[i,All]] has different length compared with `check` or `replacevec`.

Comment: @ubpdqn: each element of `mat` in row being compared with `check` element.  For example, any numbers in first row of `mat` that is less than the first value of `check` vector (check[[1]]) will be replaced with the first element of `replacevec` (replacevec[[1]]) and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the variable in the post:

```
MapThread[
 Function[{x, y, z}, x /. a_?(# < y &) :> z], {mat, check, 
  replacevec}]
```

yields:

```
{{19.8134, 54.7015, 64.1866, 75.5597, 88.8358, 83.7313, 93.0299, 
  88.2537, 101.03, 108.873, 91.8731, 88.097, 82.0075, 88.7164, 
  83.5672, 69.9254, 56.0149, 31.4328, 19.4179, 79.4021, 79.4021, 
  79.4021, 79.4021, 79.4021, 79.4021}, {24.2741, 52.6815, 64.4667, 
  74.8593, 87.6222, 87.1926, 96.3407, 90.0667, 98.2519, 103.496, 
  89.7926, 85.1259, 83.4889, 88.7111, 86.1852, 75.4296, 53.7778, 
  34.0667, 19.6889, 79.5033, 79.5033, 79.5033, 79.5033, 79.5033, 
  79.5033}, {18.4632, 50.6544, 60.5735, 72.5441, 86.0956, 84.9485, 
  91.1103, 84.8603, 94.3897, 100.463, 83.6324, 82.9412, 77.4853, 
  79.6324, 77.9485, 61.9118, 48.7574, 27.8309, 13.8824, 74.4576, 
  74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576}, {19.1212, 59.0985, 
  71.6818, 86.8182, 96.553, 91.5455, 100.402, 92.6515, 111.068, 
  111.909, 95.7803, 94.3864, 92.75, 90.8182, 95.3561, 86.197, 73.6136,
   51.5682, 40.6742, 15.1515, 88.3645, 88.3645, 88.3645, 88.3645, 
  88.3645}, {19.6083, 55.5917, 66.5583, 75.575, 87.6, 89.1417, 
  96.1083, 92.6917, 108.375, 117.3, 96.7333, 91.8167, 86.6583, 
  91.7333, 93.45, 79.5333, 60.275, 36.95, 24.3583, 9.60833, 83.8877, 
  83.8877, 83.8877, 83.8877, 83.8877}}
```

Comment: Awesome!! It works. I'm curious since I am new to mathematica, are there any sources or references that help improving my coding skills ?

Comment: @newbie I am sorry for delay in replying. The Wolfram documentation is excellent. This includes that within Mathematica and from the Wolfram portal which includes video tutorials. Searching and participating in this site is extremely helpful. I am sorry I am using mobile device and hyperlinking is difficult.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use

```
Transpose[Replace[#, v_ /; And @@ Positive[check - v] :> replacevec] & /@ Transpose@mat]
```

> {{19.8134, 54.7015, 64.1866, 75.5597, 88.8358, 83.7313, 93.0299, 
>         88.2537, 101.03, 108.873, 91.8731, 88.097, 82.0075, 88.7164, 
>         83.5672, 69.9254, 56.0149, 31.4328, 19.4179, 6.40299, 79.4021, 
>         79.4021, 79.4021, 79.4021, 79.4021}, {24.2741, 52.6815, 64.4667, 
>         74.8593, 87.6222, 87.1926, 96.3407, 90.0667, 98.2519, 103.496, 
>         89.7926, 85.1259, 83.4889, 88.7111, 86.1852, 75.4296, 53.7778, 
>         34.0667, 19.6889, 7.40741, 79.5033, 79.5033, 79.5033, 79.5033, 
>         79.5033}, {18.4632, 50.6544, 60.5735, 72.5441, 86.0956, 84.9485, 
>         91.1103, 84.8603, 94.3897, 100.463, 83.6324, 82.9412, 77.4853, 
>         79.6324, 77.9485, 61.9118, 48.7574, 27.8309, 13.8824, 5.96324, 
>         74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576, 74.4576}, {19.1212, 59.0985, 
>         71.6818, 86.8182, 96.553, 91.5455, 100.402, 92.6515, 111.068, 
>         111.909, 95.7803, 94.3864, 92.75, 90.8182, 95.3561, 86.197, 73.6136,
>          51.5682, 40.6742, 15.1515, 88.3645, 88.3645, 88.3645, 88.3645, 
>         88.3645}, {19.6083, 55.5917, 66.5583, 75.575, 87.6, 89.1417, 
>         96.1083, 92.6917, 108.375, 117.3, 96.7333, 91.8167, 86.6583, 
>         91.7333, 93.45, 79.5333, 60.275, 36.95, 24.3583, 9.60833, 83.8877, 
>         83.8877, 83.8877, 83.8877, 83.8877}}

Comment: I think the number on the first row, which is  6.40299 (output[[1,-6]]) should be replaced with 79.4021.

Comment: So I actually misunderstood your question... I think @ubpdqn's answer is what you want.